# Unklare Funktion zwei Wörter im Nebensatz

Tags: sentence-structure

> Nachgezüchtete Jungvögel werden üblicherweise mit geschlossenen Ringen beringt (was nur im Nestlingsalter möglich ist). Die in der wissenschaftlichen Beringung verwendeten **offenen Ringe** können hingegen auch später angelegt und gewechselt werden, was einen Herkunftsnachweis wertlos **machen** und damit diese Funktion **der** gefährden kann.

Beziehen sich **machen** und **der** auf die **offenen Ringe**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bei dem Satz handelt es sich um eine im Deutschen üblich zu findene Abkürzung, wenn zwei Sätze das gleiche Hilfsverb haben:

> [...] was einen Herkunftsnachweis wertlos machen **kann** und damit diese Funktion der gefährden **kann**.

Der zweite Teil des Satzes ist falsch. Vermutlich wurde nur ein Wort vergessen:

> [...] und damit diese Funktion der Ringe gefährden kann.

Alternativ kann man Ringe weglassen, dann muss man allerdings korrekt deklinieren:

> [...] und damit diese Funktion **derer** gefährden kann.

Comment: Der **Ringe**, oder der **Beringung** (als Vorgang) wäre möglich. "Diese Funktion" der Ringe/Beringung bezieht sich übrigens auf den Herkunftsnachweis des Vogels: Wenn der Ring eines erwachsenen Vogels geschlossen ist, weiß man, dass er einem Küken aufgezogen wurde (später ist der Fuß zu groß) und hat einen Herkunftsnachweis. Einen offenen Ring kann man jederzeit aufmachen und wechseln, also taugt er nicht als Herkunftsnachweis.

Comment: Die Funktion der Beringung klingt aber ziemlich gestelzt.